# Validity of DLCQ Matrix Theory near the Big Bang

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, matrix-model

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0506180) paper,section 3.2, Craps, Sethi and Verlinde claim that DLCQ matrix theory is valid near the big bang if

1. The open string oscillators decouple and
2. Gravity decouples from the matrix description

then proceeds to derive conditions for the validity of Matrix theory

Why do these conditions ensure the validity of DLCQ matrix theory? Why do open strings decouple as their lengths become small? Why is the decoupling of closed strings the same as Matrix theory decoupling from gravity? I understand that these questions probably have very overlapping answers, so I'm not necessarily looking for answers in order.

Thanks in advance.